# Saving gzipped JSON causes connection resets

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have a [gzipped JSON file](http://auction-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/auction-data/4923213e5eb3ec3b7e03d22b632bda36/auctions.json) that I'm trying to download, but when I try and read the response content with the requests library, it resets the connection.

```
data = requests.request("GET", i, stream=True)
with gzip.open(i.rsplit("/")[-1], "wb") as fh:
  for chunk in data.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    fh.write(chunk)
```

Here is what I get when I try to read the content:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 228, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 501, in read_chunked
    chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 461, in _handle_chunk
    value = self._fp._safe_read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 592, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 664, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 349, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 526, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 246, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Programming/Python/warehouse/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    compile_auctions(slugs)
  File "H:/Programming/Python/warehouse/main.py", line 44, in compile_auctions
    for chunk in data.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
  File "H:\Programming\Python\virtualenvs\warehouse\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 667, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

I can read the JSON in my browser and in Postman, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10.

Is this the proper way to save gzipped JSON?

Answer (score 0):

requests already decompress the data.

You do not need to use gzip:

```
import requests

req = requests.get("http://auction-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/auction-data/4923213e5eb3ec3b7e03d22b632bda36/auctions.json", stream=True)

with open("out.json", "wb") as f:
    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: On my machine, this is working as expected. Did the host blacklist you because of too many requests?? Edit: This was a reply to a deleted comment

Comment: It turns out the issue was something else, not my code. Thanks, though!

Comment: @mynameismevin Can you reveal what was the issue? I'm struggling with the same error.

Comment: @Adam It looks like it's a bug with Python 3.5.1, and how it makes system calls. I didn't have the same problem with the API in different languages.

Comment: @mynameismevin I had this problem on Python 3.4.5, but I ended up with retrying failed requests and it kind-of solved the problem for me

Comment: @Adam, gotcha! I ended up going with a different language, glad you solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue isn't actually with the API I'm using, it's either a bug with the requests library for Windows or an issue with Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10.

When I ran this exact code on Ubuntu 16.04 using Python 3.5.1, it worked just fine.